# Finding the range of $p$ such that $p = 3 \cos^2 x + 4 \sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

> Find the range of possible values for $p$ such that
> $$3 \cos^2 x + 4 \sin x = p$$

I tried:
$$\begin{align}
p &=  \frac{1}{2}(8\sin(x) + 3\cos 2 x + 3) \tag1\\[4pt]
  &= -\frac32\sin^2x + 4\sin x  + \frac32\cos^2x + \frac32 \tag2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Show your attempts before

Comment: 1/2 (8 sin(x) + 3 cos(2 x) + 3) = p
-(3 sin^2(x))/2 + 4 sin(x) + (3 cos^2(x))/2 + 3/2 = p

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should edit your question to include a description of what you've tried. People tend to get upset if they think you want them to do your homework for you. If we know where you're stuck, though, we can give more precise feedback to help you better ^_^

Comment: It is immediate that you can get substitute the cosine.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$3(1-\sin^2x)+4\sin{x}=p$$ or
$$\sin^2x-\frac{4}{3}\sin{x}=1-\frac{p}{3}$$ or
$$\left(\sin{x}-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2=\frac{13-3p}{9},$$ which gives firstly $$p\leq\frac{13}{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $\sin{x}=\frac{2}{3},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Also, $p(\sin{x})=-3\sin^2x+4\sin{x}+3$ is a concave function, which says that $p$ gets a minimal value for an extreme value of $\sin,$ which happens for $\sin{x}=1$ or for $\sin{x}=-1.$

$p(1)=4$ and $p(-1)=-4$ and since $p$ is a continuous function we got the answer:
$$\left[-4,\frac{13}{3}\right]$$

Comment: why is the first case impossible, i'm sorry i'm really bad at math

Comment: @weerie Elexa '04 Because $-1\leq\sin{x}\leq1,$ but $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}>1.$

Comment: one more question, why is  p≤7? is it because we subtract 7 with p?

Comment: @weerieElexa'04 because LHS is $\geq 0$

Comment: ahhh okayy thanks

Comment: @weerie Elexa '04 Good luck!

Comment: Mh, two upvotes for a wrong answer...

Comment: @Yves Daoust Maybe you'll explain before where you think there is a mistake?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I don't see any trace of the $13/3$ nor $-4$ bounds. Did I look wrongly ? Notice that I didn't downvote yet and I was mainly addressing the upvoters.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I'll check it again. Thank you! Probably I did not understand right  the problem.

Comment: @Yves Daoust  It's indeed was delirium. I fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$p=-3\sin^2x+4\sin x+3$$ and $\sin x\in[-1,1]$.

The quadratic function $-3s^2+4s+3$ achieves the maximum $$\dfrac{13}3$$ at $s=\dfrac23$, which is in the allowed range, and the minimum is reached at an endpoint of the interval, hence the smallest of

$$\pm4.$$

[image]